# When I try to install VersionPress, it tells me, "The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found."

Tags: installation, git, plugins

I'm trying VersionPress for the first time. I downloaded the project from the [VersionPress GitHub](https://github.com/versionpress/versionpress) page, then went to Plugins>Add New in my dashboard and uploaded the zip file "versionpress-master.zip" and click the install button. Then, when the project starts loading, it takes me to a screen that reads:

> Installing Plugin from uploaded file: versionpress-master.zip
>   Unpacking the package…
>
> Installing the plugin…
>
> The package could not be installed. No valid plugins were found.
>
> Plugin installation failed.

Am I doing something wrong? I'm doing this on the version of my site that lives on my shared server, not on my local installation.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the file you downloaded, `versionpress-master.zip`, isn't structured like a WordPress plugin. When I unzip `versionpress-master.zip`, the plugin looks like it's in the directory `plugins/versionpress`. You'll need to copy that directory and all its contents to your site's plugin directory (usually `wp-content/plugins`).

**Edited to add:** The [official site's installation instructions](https://docs.versionpress.net/en/getting-started/installation-uninstallation/) indicate that  you should download the plugin zip file from their site, *not* from GitHub.

**Edited again to add:** [The plugin is no longer being developed and **does not support WordPress 5.x/Gutenberg**.](https://github.com/versionpress/versionpress/issues/1481)

Comment: That docs page is a bit outdated, you should get a ZIP file from GitHub releases instead: https://github.com/versionpress/versionpress/releases.

Comment: Getting the same error as OP. Has anyone successfully installed this WP plugin using any method?

Comment: According to the project's Github issues page, [the plugin is not compatible with Gutenberg & WordPress 5.x](https://github.com/versionpress/versionpress/issues/1481).